# UITableView not scrolling to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I'm going to link you a video showcasing my problem as it's somewhat hard to convey with words.
[UITableView not scrolling to bottom](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXlu_skSsEs&feature=youtu.be)
In the video I'm hitting a button which adds items to the list. Note that I am not stopping at Item 16, and that I am still adding more items to the list that don't get displayed. Eventually, upon added new items, the list will automatically scroll up via

```
[_items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", count]];

[self.tbl reloadData];

[self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

The main issue is towards the end of the video, where I scroll towards the last few items, but I cannot select them. Apparently the issue has to deal with the height of the UITableView. I've tried changing this in the storyboard editor but it didn't do anything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have it in an IBAction for an "Add" button. It's the one I'm pressing in the video to add items into the table.

Comment: This is probably an issue with the `UITableView`'s contentSize property being incorrect. I think I had the same problem recently, put some debugging code in to see if your content size is being updated when you add the new cells

Comment: The content size's height gets updated by 44 (default row height) each time. Obviously the width stays the same. The height starts at 109, which is where the table starts apparently. Now it only starts to automatically scroll down once the height surpasses 1024 (the height for the iPad mini). However, from height 813-1033 no new items show up. Any idea?

Comment: Your table view my be larger than the device screen size, try reducing the size of your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok from what I can see and from the comments, I think it is likely that the height of your `UITableView` is larger than the device screen size, which means it will not scroll down because the items haven't reached the bottom of the `UITableView`'s `UIScrollView`.

Go to IB and set constraints so the `UITableView` is equal to the view controllers width and height.

Comment: I did that but then it overlaps all the elements in the top. IE. the buttons in the video. Also the "view" mode is on "scale to fill" under attributes

Comment: Oh sorry forgot about the buttons. Remove the constraints and set new ones to Top and bottom space to container and the width (or leading & trailing space)

Comment: Ok it works now, but with one big error. I'm not really sure what I did but I can't undo to how it was before lol. The first video will show you how I placed the constraints of the UITableView in relation to the view controller. While the second video will show you what's going on. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nt-h88hBdT8&feature=youtu.be)                       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1zSNud1Xcs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I can't see anything there

Comment: As you can see from the second link, the autoscroll works as desired and I am finally able to see the last few items. However, the UITableView is now extremely small and the rest of the view controller is black.

Comment: Ok have you got the constraint Bottom space to bottom layout guide?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "constraint Bottom space to bottom layout"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46128/discussion-between-nic-robertson-and-user2402616)

Comment: @Esq there was no code to show. His issue was in the interface builder. His issue was solved so I'm not worried if you don't feel like liking

Answer (score 6):

Most likely `reloadData` doesn't fully execute when it gets called, because it assumes you might make more changes and tell it to reload again.

Try introducing a zero second delay, to give it a chance to run:

```
[_items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", count]];

[self.tbl reloadData];

double delayInSeconds = 0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  [self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
});
```

Also, you should not be using `reloadData` in this situation. This is how rows should be added:

```
[_items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trawl %d", count]];

[self.postsTableView beginUpdates];
[self.postsTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:_items.count - 1] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectNone]; // maybe you want some other animation here
[self.postsTableView endUpdates];

double delayInSeconds = 0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  [self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
});
```

Comment: I get use of undeclared identifier for "NSTableViewAnimationEffectNone". Also, the introduced delay had no effect.

Comment: Sorry, it's probably `UI` instead of `NS` for the animation, check the table view documentation. You should be using that instead of reloadData.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is if introducing a delay didn't fix it, maybe @Nic Robertson is correct in which case it sounds like a bug Apple needs to fix... and you need to find a workaround until then.

Comment: Yeah looks like that's my only option. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Seems most of you are wrong.

It should be like this:

```
[self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

That is, should be UITableViewScrollPositionTop, not UITableViewScrollPositionBottom. Here atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop is the origin of change, not the destination.